# Patterns of coefficients.

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am working through the book Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering and I came across [image: this example.]

Beneath the question, they stated that the root x=-1 was found from the **pattern of coefficients**. I cannot find anything about this online and so I am very much stumped. Would appreciate if anyone could shed any light on this method of finding a root.

Many thanks.

Comment: $x=1$ is a root if the coefficients sum up (as is) to $0.$ $x=-1$ is a root if the even coefficients and the negatives of the odd coefficients sum to $0.$ That's a matter of plugging $x=1$ and $x=-1$ into the equation.

Comment: There’s not a “real” method, as far as I know. Actually for polynomials of degree less than 5 there are formulas, but you don’t want to use them, trust me. I don’t know why he does that with the b’s, once you find $x=-1$ is a solution, just divide by $x+1$.

Comment: @tommy1996q The $b's$ are just the coefficients of $x^4,x^3,\dots$ I don't see any good reason to do that to solve this question. But I don't have read the book and maybe it is part of a plan.

Comment: @mfl Yes it is part of a plan they were explaining and demonstrating comparing coefficients.

Comment: @mfl yes I had understood the b’s are the coefficients, I was just saying that method seems way too tricky when you can simply divide. But it looks like it’s part of a more general topic, as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible integer roots of $f(x)=3x^4-x^3-10x^2-2x+4=0$ are the divisors of $4.$ That is $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 4.$ It easy to get that

$$f(1)=3-1-10-2+4\ne 0,$$ which shows that $x=1$ is not a root, and 
$$f(-1)=3+1-10+2+4=0,$$ which shows that $x=-1$ is a root. In other words, the sum of the coefficients is not zero and thus $x=1$ is not a root. And the sum of the coefficients of even degree minus the sum of the coefficients of odd degree is zero and thus $x=-1$ is a root.

Now, the way to factor $f(x)$ is not the shortest nor the simplest. Since $x=-1$ is a root we have that

$$3x^4-x^3-10x^2-2x+4=(x+1)(b_3x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0).$$ Identifying the coefficients of $x^4$ we have $$b_3=3;$$ identifying the coefficients of $x^3$ we have $$b_2+b_3=-1,$$ and so on.

If we use Ruffini's rule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) we will get the answer quickly. Or just make the division.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the pointer towards Ruffini's rule. That's a real time saver.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they mean is simply this: Begin by supposing that -1  could be a root.  Plug -1 into the expression.  We get:

3 - (-1) - 10 - (-2) + 4 = 3 + 1 - 10 + 2 + 4 = 0

which confirms our supposition.

More generally, it is a good idea to try plugging a few small-magnitude integers into the algebraic expression because the result is a relatively simple arithmetic expression.  Values 0, 1, and -1 in particular are good choices because their powers are trivial to evaluate.  If the polynomial is monic, of course, one tries factors of the constant term.